# onclick in Opa code not working

Tags: mongodb, opa

Click me bottom in the bellow code does not work

```
database int /counter = 0;
/** action _*/
function action(_){
    /counter++;
    #msg = <div>Thank you, user number {/counter}!</div>
}
/** page */
function page(){
    <h1 id="msg">Hello</h1>
    <a onclick={action}>Click me</a>
}

Server.start(Server.http,
  { title: "Database Demo!", page: page }
)
```

I compiled the code in the following way and opa also installed for me mongodb

```
$ opa thank.opa --
Http serving on http://mic:8080
DbGen/Mongo Looking for MongoDB in directory '/home/mictadlo/.opa/mongo'
DbGen/Mongo MongoDB does not seem to be installed in '/home/mictadlo/.opa/mongo'
DbGen/Mongo Please wait while Opa downloads MongoDB from 'http://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.8.tgz'...
DbGen/Mongo MongoDB was downloaded (/home/mictadlo/.opa/mongo/mongo.tgz)
DbGen/Mongo Uncompressing of MongoDB archive... (tar -xvzf /home/mictadlo/.opa/mongo/mongo.tgz -C /home/mictadlo/.opa/mongo)
DbGen/Mongo MongoDB seems launched (pid:4494)
```

Why does click me link does not work?

Comment: If I remove counter variable and the first line then onclick works. It seems that somehow the Mongo conection does not work.

Comment: Are you positive database server is alive? Can you connect with `mongo` shell after you start your application.

Comment: Thank you, I had to use option smallfiles with this command "mongod --noprealloc --smallfiles --dbpath ~/.opa/mongo/data", because not enough HDD was avaible. Than I could start it with "./thank.js --db-remote localhost:27017" and the site was working. If I change the code now do I have to use opa command and than ./thank.js or is there a shortcut to just use one command to compile and execute. Unfortunately, it does not work to use "opa thank.opa --" with MongoDB.

Comment: Update, I had to use option smallfiles with this command "mongod --noprealloc --smallfiles --dbpath ~/.opa/mongo/data", because not enough HDD was avaible. Than I could start it with "./thank.js --db-remote localhost:27017" or "opa thank.opa --"